# Slow Printing with Ricoh PS Universal 4.8.0.1from Windows 2012 on Windows 7 Client

Tags: windows, networking, printing, printer, windows-server-2012

We have a Windows 2012 server with 108 Printers. We have about 70 queues with Ricoh PS Driver for Universal Print 4.8.0.1. This server was migrated from a Windows 2003 server with same queues and Drivers were upgraded as required. The site has been experiencing very slow printing.

When I ping the server with -l 4096 I get the following end results.

```
Packets: Sent = 163, Received = 154, Lost = 9 (5% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 252ms, Maximum = 404ms, Average = 282ms
```

So I asked Network team to check on it and they said to replace the cable on a switch.They said that "we are observing server connected port negotiating with 100Mbps Half duplex. This happens when there is a problem with Patch card/patch panel or server end NIC setting. We would suggest you check and hard code NIC settings to 1000Mbps full duplex if the still issue is not resolved kindly engage cabling team and replace the cable on server connected port. "

On the server, we have set the Speed & Duplex to 1.0GBPS Full Duplex from Auto Negotiation.

Also while pinging the printer from the server there is no loss. The same queues on Windows 2003 work without any issues.

So could the packet loss be the cause of this or there may be any other reason? Also, how can I determine where the loss is happening?

EDIT: Seems to be the issue was indeed packet loss. The switch had hard coded 100Mbps NIC and on Server, it was negotiating at half duplex. Changed both settings to 1000Mbps full duplex. Now it looks like it only takes about a minute or less to print the 10 pages of that PDF file. It will print two pages and there is a delay of about 4 seconds and then print the next 2 two pages and it continues that process until all the pages are all printed. So it is partially fixed but not completely.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Ricoh Print&Share](http://www.printandshare.info) virtual driver you can turn of WMI and/or SNMP in the general settings which sometimes helps. Maybe this is something you could look at?

Comment: Ricoh Print & Share is not something we use in the environment. I think there would be huge cost and efforts needed in deploying this (300+ Print Servers, Over 20,000 Printers worldwide) Also SNMP settings does not seem to help.

Comment: It was just an idea as with changing these settings it sometimes fixes delays or reduces network traffic.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for it. SNMP did not work. Any other idea where there might be a delay? Can there be a way to identify via packet tracing where the delay is happening? 

Or any guide where to look further or the path to start would be greatly appreciated